# .NET5 build crashes with BigSur (SIGABRT)

Tags: macos, .net-5, macos-big-sur

when i try to build my .net5 solution the dotnet application crashes and i got following log message:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

The curious thing is, if i ignore the crash, the application builds after a few minutes..
and it doesn't matter whether I build via rider or via the console

.NET 5.0.101.
Mac V11.1 Big Sur
and developing with JetBrains Rider 2020.3

Comment: Can you reproduce with a new, empty project? If so, you may need to reinstall the .NET SDK and/or report the issue to Microsoft

Comment: i tried it with a example web api solution from rider and anything is fine :(

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i got this message too:
 ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.ThreadPool

Comment: Might need to report that to Microsoft then, don't think the SO community will be of much help

Comment: Have you try this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12317

Comment: @ThorstenRintelen i already renewed the certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to partially solve the problem.

First i ran the projects in a docker. The projects were build without any problems.

What did I do to run it on BigSur:

- uninstalled all .net sdks and runtimes. ([dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh))
- net5.0.101 reinstalled ([net5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0))
- deleted and cloned the repository
- execute dotnet build in the cli
- et voila - its builds without any problems!

unfortunately, when i build the projects with rider, dotnet still crashes. It looks like it is an issue by Jetbrains Rider